# Access - Make relationship between tables

Tags: ms-access, foreign-keys, relationship

I am a newbie in Access database and I have a small project to make a relationship between tables.

My project is:

There has a company test for mobile phone (Samsung, nokia, iphone...)
For each customer (ex: customer samsung), it has a many models (ex: A, J, Note...), for each model it has a many versions (ex: 1, 2, 3, 4...).

And for each version, there will have many tasks to test it (ex: task test monitor, task test battery...). For each task, there has a tester to test it.

I create a relationship between table like below picture:

[image]

So, the relationship is:
1 customer has many models (ex: Samsung has model A)
1 model has many Versions (ex: For A model has version 3)
1 version has many task (ex: samsung A5 need to test monitor, test battery, test Audio..)
And Tom is a tester who test both monitor and battery for samsung A3, Ted who test Audio for samsung A3.

But my Problem is:
Version is sometimes duplicated. and It's seem to be can't a Primary key.
For ex: We get a customer Iphone, with S model and version 3. Now, when we have Task with version 3, Is it will belong to Samsung or Iphone?

I probably still not understand all of relationship but please help tell me what wrong in this relationship.

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Should probably use autonumber type field as primary key.

Comment: Hi. Access is a tool for describing designs. You need to read & follow an introductory information modeling & database design textbook so you know how to design something. Knowing that some things of some kind are in some way each associated with some possible number of other things of some kind is not sufficient for making a design about those things & their association(s)/relation(ship)(s). If you are following a textbook, show what steps you have followed. Otherwise find one & do that.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices in the Version table:

1. Create an autonumeric field, ex. Id and make it the primary key.
   Usualy I create Id field as PK for every table
2. Make the primary key composed by Model and Version. But, be aware
   that some makers can name their models the same. So I think that
   first option is better choice